# Undefined property axios and raw github content

Tags: javascript, github, axios

I'm trying to `GET` a json file on GitHub with the following code, everything used to work as expected until last week, but now the actual data retrieved is messed up. It actually returns an array of numbers? Setting `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers didn't do anything.
I can't really explain this behaviour and would really appreciate some help!

```
axios
  .get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/speckleworks/SpeckleManagerFeed/master/repos.json")
  .then(resp => {
    console.log(resp.data);
    // RETURNS:
    // {
    //  "connectorRepos":[
    //           {
    //        "name":"SpeckleGSA",
    //        "owner":"arup-group",
    //        ...
    console.log(resp.data.connectorRepos);
    // RETURNS:
    // undefined
    console.log(Object.keys(resp.data));
    // RETURNS
    // ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", ...
    let x = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(resp.data))
    console.log(Object.keys(x));
    // RETURNS
    // ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", ...
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("Unable to obtain repos list. " + err);
    return;
  });
```

Comment: Looks like Github isn't setting the response header for Content-Type to `application/json`; resp.data is therefore a String. You need to do `const data = JSON.parse(resp.data);` first, now you can access `data.connectorRepos` etc.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG, I tried that but `JSON.parse` fails with `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 1725` but it *is* valid json, I have validated it with external tools...

Comment: It's not valid; there's a trailing comma in line 47.

Comment: Afraid that's not the issue, removed the trailing comma and parsing still fails `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`. If the issue had to do with the content type, `console.log(Object.keys(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(resp.data))));` should work I believe, but it's not...

Comment: That error means the object got force converted to a string, in this case `"[object Object]"`, and you're trying to parse that as if it's JSON. The usual cause is that `JSON.parse()` is called on an object. The JSON is indeed fine now, as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/bwofqeua/ I suspect axios is auto-parsing it as JSON (because it's no longer invalid, so now again, you can directly access `resp.data.connectorRepos` and don't need to parse yourself)

Comment: Omg, thanks so much! Would have never though a trailing comma would have invalidated it! Feel free to post it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by Chris in the comments above, the json file had an extra trailing comma and couldn't get parsed by axios/JSON.parse().